# How to make the following type of listview in which every row is different

Tags: android, listview

[image]

Comment: Probably easier would be just to use a linear layout. If there are only few elements and all different use of list view component is a bit questionable.

Comment: thats the main issue Juhani :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use a `ListView`, you'll need to implement your own [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). The `Adapter` API supports using different views depending on the list item, so you'll just implement `getViewItemType` and `getView` to use a different view depending on which item it's asking about. How you do this is up to you.

However, if you actually want what you see in the screenshot which is a list of preferences, why not use [`PreferenceScreen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html)?

Comment: Because `PreferenceScreen` is much more limiting to what you can do

Comment: Of course binnyb - that's why I only suggested it conditionally.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by limiting. You can also add your own Preferences in the PreferenceScreen. Just extend the Preference class and and your own stuff there (i.e. scroll bar, or whatever you like)

Comment: thankyou so much guyss.....it was indeed very helpful :) :).....for more precise answer see the link below which i have posted